# How to redirect after Woocommerce new account password set?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

so to quickly paint the picture:

- I'm using Woocommerce - CartFlows
- after purchase (free product) a user gets an email from Woo with the link to set his password
- but there's a weird issue, after successful password reset, the first try to login doesn't work. I tried disabling all plugins but still the same problem.

So now I want to solve this by redirecting the user to /wp-login.php page after successfull password reset.

An even better solution would be to auto login and redirect the user to a page.

Is this possible and how?

Thanks!

Already tried some functions found here but it seems they are all depleted.